# How to Geometrically see the Null-space from the Geometric transformation meaning of Matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, linear-transformations, systems-of-equations

In this [3blue1brown](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uQhTuRlWMxw&list=PL0-GT3co4r2y2YErbmuJw2L5tW4Ew2O5B&index=8) video on null-spaces, he said and showed the collection of those points in the original vector space that after transformation by the matrix $A$ are moved to origin.

I know the geometric transformation of a Matrix and how the original vector space is transformed by the Maytrix in to a new vector space.

I know the Rank Calculation and solving Homogeneous equation using Jordan Reduction in Row echelon form.

But How to geometrically find those points that will transform into origin, after applying the transformation?

Like how the x-axis and y-axis are collapsing, from that information can we infer the nullspace, i.e. the points collapsing into origin?

At least how  the Jordan Reduction is doing that for us, can you explain geometrically?

For example, taking the matrix:

$\begin{bmatrix}1&1\\0&0\end{bmatrix}$

I am imagining, the $x$-axis all grid-lines sitting there only, but the $y$-axis rotating to right by $90^\circ$. Thus in this geometric interpretation, the line $y=-x$ is the collection of points that are squished into origin as given by Jordan Elimination, but **how to see Geometrically**?

Thank you!

Comment: Maybe it helps to know that, by the "four subspaces" theorem, the null space of $A$ is the orthogonal complement of the row space of $A$. If you can visualize the row space of $A$, then you can visualize its orthogonal complement. (And by the way, the row space of $A$ is the same thing as the range of $A^T$.) For your example matrix, the row space is the span of the vector $\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}$, so the null space is the span of the orthogonal vector $\begin{bmatrix} -1 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}$.

Comment: @littleO Yes! Now I can see that! the rowspace was missing in the picture! And by the same we can "also prove that the null space has dimensions = $n-rank(A)$ ? Where $n$ is domain of A ?

Answer (score 1):

You should not expect to be able to "see" the null space geometrically in all problems; after all the technique for solving (homogeneous) linear systems algebraically was invented for a purpose. However for the $2\times2$ case, one can manage to do this reasonably well. The two columns of the matrix tell where the standard basis vectors $\binom10$ and $\binom01$ go respectively, and *unless* these two images are proportional the null space will be just $\{\binom00\}$. If these images are (not both zero and) proportional, say as $a:b$ (in the example you have $1:1$), then a vector $\binom xy$ will be in the null space if and only if the contributions from its two coordinates annihilate each other, that is if $ax+by=0$ (which you can also write $by=-ax$); an example of such a vector is $\binom{-b}a$.